# Unable to select S3 folder as the source for CodePipeline on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I'm trying to setup a CI/CD pipeline on AWS using CodePipeline with the following setup

Source: S3

Build: CodeBuild

Deploy: CodeDeploy

Release: EC2 instance

I've managed to finish the config by following [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/tutorials-simple-s3.html)

However my pipeline fails with the error message that

```
The object with key 'code-sashi/api' does not exist.
```

I have checked and confirmed that the bucket name is correct and there is a folder 'api' inside the bucket.

The option to set this clearly states that I can enter either the S3 object key or an S3 folder. I would like to use an S3 folder in this case since my build artifact will only be ready after CodeBuild runs.

However CodePipeline continues to look for an object key and ignores my folder.

I have also tried setting the S3 folder as 'api', '/api', 'api/' and none of them work. I tried copying my files to the bucket directly and setting the folder as '/' which fails with a different error message that "object key cannot end with a trailing /"

Based on this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/create-project.html#create-project-console) I should be able to get all the contents of the bucket by S3 folder as '/'.

If it helps, I am uploading files from Bitbucket private repository to S3 using Bitbucket Pipelines. Unfortunately CodePipeline cannot connect Bitbucket directly and hence the S3 workaround. Weird that CodeBuild has no problems connecting to a Bitbucket repository but it cannot do so if it is a part of CodePipeline.

**Question**

How do I configure CodePipeline correctly to get my files from 'code-sashi' bucket and 'api' folder? There will be other folders containing code in the future so I would like to hold all of them inside a single bucket.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured this out finally.

Even if you want to use S3 as your source rather than your artifact storage, the files must be zipped and you must specify the zipped file as your object key.

So I added a zip stage to my Bitbucket Pipeline and re-configured CodePipeline to use the zipped file as the source. Worked perfectly!

Comment: I'm glad you managed to figure this out. I think you can still specify an individual file from S3 even if it's not a ZIP file (not sure how you would use that, I can't think of actions that don't accept artifacts as zip files), but as you've discovered, if you specify a prefix ("directory") then we won't zip it for you.

Comment: Funny thing I had the same issue and they just updated the documentation  to say you can only use a file, not a folder